# Apportable support on SpriteKit

Tags: android, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, apportable

I'm creating a small 2D game in Xcode. I use SpriteKit for all the game graphics, but no physics at all.
I'm trying to use Apportable to generate an Android test version, but it fails to generate the .apk. It fails to find the SpriteKit, and I have no idea why. I read that Apportable supports SpriteKit so maybe this is something simpler, like me not providing the right paths to files or something. Any hint?

```
Warning: Module SpriteKit not found
Warning: Module SpriteKit not found
[1/68] Compiling /Users/XXX/Documents/Code/GameApp/WSDictionary.m
[2/68] Compiling /Users/XXX/Documents/Code/GameApp/WSGameScene.m
...


In file included from /Users/XXX/Documents/Code/GameApp/WSDictionary.m:9:
In file included from /Users/XXX/Documents/Code/GameApp/WSDictionary.h:10:
/Users/XXX/Documents/Code/GameApp/WSGameboard.h:10:9: fatal error: 'SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h' file not found
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteKit is no longer available in the Apportable public SDK. More details on the [Apportable Forum](http://forum.apportable.com/t/spritekit-in-developer-preview/252)

Comment: to expound slightly: we recommend moving your game to cocos2d--it's more fully featured and being actively developed